# Proving infinity norm is equivalent to the L2 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I know that two norms are equivalent if 
$c\lVert x\rVert_a \leq \lVert x\rVert_b \leq d\lVert x\rVert_a$, however I am struggling to apply this in order to show $\lVert x \rVert_2 \leq d\lVert x \rVert_\infty$. My approach is something like this:

we can show that $\lVert x\rVert_2 \leq d\lVert x\rVert_\infty$ by squaring both sides and multiplying the right side by a constant n, where n is the size of the vector to get $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 \leq n * \max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} x_i^2 = n*\lVert x \rVert_\infty^2$, which means that $\lVert x\rVert_2 \leq  \sqrt{n}\lVert x\rVert_\infty$. However I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: what you have done is fine

Comment: Is there a way to find the constant as a opposed to just assuming it is n?

Comment: you aren't assuming anything! you just found a constant that happens to be the square root of the dimension of the space

Comment: @user1775500 If you're wondering if this is the best possible constant, try to find a vector $x$ satisfying this bound with equality.